# website layout not working correctly on older versions of IE - works fine on IE9, FF 13 and chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have created my first site and put alot of time into it and I'm confuse I have tested the site on my browsers

IE9
Chrome 19.0.1084.56 m
Firefox 13.0

My layout all works for me

In checking previous browsers like IE8, IE7 etc the buttons on my menu are not even displaying properly I have an image as a button with a rollover image over the top.

They are either half showing the underlying image or not at all and then when clicked on half disappear etc..

I really would like to get some help from an experienced person out there to let me know the best thing to do when it come to my website.

Has it got anything to do with the size of the graphics etc? or the way I have done my CSS coding for the rollover buttons??

any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm sorry that I'm a beginner but I have tried to learn what I can and watched hundreds of youtube videos and website tutorials... so I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: we will only help with specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 148 of style.css you are missing a `.` on a class selector `menu li a:visited` should be `.menu li a:visited`. Some browsers may drop the rule completely if that cannot parse it. Double check your CSS.

Not really relevant since you are using html5 shiv, but worth mentioning:

*Additionally, you are using `section` elements and relying on them to style things. Those are from HTML5 so some browsers wont recognize them and thus will not apply your css. If you want to support older browsers (and any new ones that don't support certain HTML5 elements) then use DIV or other elements as containers instead.*

Comment: He is loading the html5 shiv so html5 elements should be fine

Comment: Thanks I appreciate all feedback and advice as I have just tried to learn what I can off youtube etc so I probably was using the wrong coding

Kizzie (girl)

Comment: Thanks prodigitalson - it fixed it - I didnt realise if you added more than one class on the same line it needed a period. So I actually never missed it I just didnt know - so now I learnt something new again! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HTML5, you are going to have serious problems with older versions of IE.  To fix these, add these lines of code to each webpage before the closing  tag:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: thanks for your time - do you mean the closing tag before the /html

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/ here it says to put it in the header before the body tag... sorry for probably another obvious beginner question.

Comment: it needs to be included between <head> and </head>

Comment: if you are unsure, just look for </head> and place that code right before it

Comment: Thankyou!!! I wish I could rep you guys for helping me but I cant yet so I hope Thankyou is enough ! When I get more int he future I will come back and rep you all - Cheers so much!

Comment: no problem.  good luck learning HTML!

Answer (score 0):

You using HTML5 tags so, you have to add http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/ for IE8-

Also you have some JS errors.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate all feedback and advice as I have just tried to learn what I can off youtube etc so I probably was using the wrong coding

Kizzie (girl)